# Require and Regex with vee-validate

Tags: attributes, required, vee-validate

I'm attempting to set a required and regex attributes with vee-validate.  The regex bit [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/23ctgxo7/), but as soon as I add the required attribute the entire control [disappears from the form](https://jsfiddle.net/ev02s5wm/).

This works fine ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23ctgxo7/)), but missing required attribute (multiline for easier reading):

```
<input 
  v-validate="{ regex:/^((\d{3})[ -]|(\d{3}[ -]?)){2}\d{4}$/ }" 
  :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('phonenumber') }" 
  class="input is-primary" 
  name="phonenumber" 
  type="text" 
  placeholder="404-555-1212"
> <!-- end input -->
```

This causes the entire form to disappear ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ev02s5wm/)) (multiline for easier reading):

```
<input 
  v-validate="{ required|regex:/^((\d{3})[ -]|(\d{3}[ -]?)){2}\d{4}$/ }" 
  :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('phonenumber') }" 
  class="input is-primary" 
  name="phonenumber" 
  type="text" 
  placeholder="404-555-1212"
> <!-- end input -->
```

I've tried using a comma to separate vee-validate attributes, but this also fails in the same manner.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to include `required: true,` in order for the attribute to work correctly.

Like this:

```
<input 
  v-validate="{ required: true, regex:/^((\d{3})[ -]|(\d{3}[ -]?)){2}\d{4}$/ }" 
  :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('phonenumber') }" 
  class="input is-primary" 
  name="phonenumber" 
  type="text" 
  placeholder="404-555-1212"
> <!-- end input -->
```